# column names in 2nd row of csv file

Tags: r, csv

I have a csv file with a blank row above the column names.
Is it possible to correct for this in R?

Right now, I open the csv and remove the blank row before running the R code. But I want to avoid this work if I can.

What is the correct/best way to remove the blank row and then label the columns.

I have tried:

```
 df <- read.csv("SourceFile/filename.csv", header= TRUE, row.names = 2)
```

but I get this error:

Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names

Comment: `read.csv` should have a `skip` option

Comment: If the row is totally blank it will be skipped automatically. `txt <- "\n\none,two\n1,2"; read.csv(text=txt, header=TRUE)` - `blank.lines.skip = TRUE` is the default. I suspect something else is wrong here, possibly a quoting character in a field. Try setting `quote=""` as an argument too.

Answer (score 1):

In the `readr` package, the `read_csv` function has a `skip` argument. https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_delim.html

There is also a `skip_empty_rows` argument if you want to be more aggressive.

Comment: `read.csv` has a `skip=` argument too, and it also skips blank lines by default.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, try:

```
read.csv(...,skip=1)
```

Hope this is helpful!